# GETDATE() minus 1/2 not same as minus 0.5

Tags: sql-server

Why is `GETDATE()-(1/2)` not the same as `GETDATE()-(0.5)` (MSSQL v11)??

```
SELECT GETDATE()-(1/2), GETDATE()-(0.5)
----------------------- -----------------------
2017-09-11 14:57:17.903 2017-09-11 02:57:17.903
```

When I grew up 1/2 was the same as 0.5

Comment: check out the result of `select 1/2`, its not what you think.

Comment: the answer is integer division

Comment: Even when you sort this out, I'd strongly suggest that you use `DATEADD` and make your logic *explicit* if you're wanting to e.g. find a time 12 hours earlier.

Comment: You can try 1.0/2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, thanks to the comments I realized 1/2 is implicitly and unfortunately interpreted as integer division and rounded (strangely) down to 0.

Comment: yes, Daniels answer is the solution: simply use 1.0 or 2.0 instead of the inetger...

Comment: I don't see why it's "unfortunate". It's an integer dividing another integer, it would be unfortunate that SQL Server decided to suddenly don't respect data types

Comment: Tomayto, tomahto. 1 is a number equal to 1.0. MSSQL may think it's an integer and that it fits zero times into 2 but any child can tell you 1/2 is 0.5. It's like saying that 1 + 2 is 12 because 1 and 2 are strings. Can't see why anyone would need 1/2 to be 0.

Answer (score 0):

It is not rounded.
when using integers x/y is like asking how many times y can fit in x,
The leftover (modulo) is x-(x/y)*y

```
1/2 = 0
1%2 = 1  
1 = (1/2)*2 + 1%2
x = (x/y)*y + x%y
```